# Prevent ggarrange() from hiding significance stars on plot(?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, data-visualization, ggpubr

**I am using this function:**

```
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RemPsyc/niceplots/master/niceViolinFunction.R")
```

**To do these two plots:**

```
(niceViolin(group = mtcars$cyl,
            response = mtcars$mpg,
            comp1 = 1,
            comp2 = 3) -> plot1)
```

[image]

```
(niceViolin(group = mtcars$cyl,
            response = mtcars$disp,
            comp1 = 1,
            comp2 = 3) -> plot2)
```

[image]

**I would like to `ggarrange` them, like this:**

```
library(ggpubr)
(fig1 <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2,
                   labels = c("A", "B"),
                   ncol = 1, nrow = 2))
```

[image]

## Problem

As you can see, the `ggarrangement` hides part of the asterisks (significance stars) unless I save them with a much higher height (which I do not want).

[image]

## Question

What's the best way to deal with this?

Note: arranging them horizontally is not a solution as I provided a minimally reproducible example, but assume there's a large matrix of plots. Also open to changing the underlying function as under the hood the problem seems related to `ggsignif()` and `geom_signif`.

Comment: I found `patchwork` package to be way easier to use for layouting several plots

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for an automatized solution, but a workaround is to manually change the y-axis scale maximum by mimicking (as closely as possible) the automatic values. By making the y-axis just a bit higher, it can accommodate the asterisks. However, sometimes (e.g., figure 2) the y-axis won't look exactly the same as the original because of this tweak.

```
(niceViolin(group = mtcars$cyl,
            response = mtcars$mpg,
            ymin = 10,
            ymax = 37,
            yby = 5,
            comp1 = 1,
            comp2 = 3) -> plot1)

(niceViolin(group = mtcars$cyl,
            response = mtcars$disp,
            ymin = 50,
            ymax = 520,
            yby = 100,
            comp1 = 1,
            comp2 = 3) -> plot2)

# Corrected ggarrangement
library(ggpubr)
(fig1 <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2,
                   labels = c("A", "B"),
                   ncol = 1, nrow = 2))
```

[image]